# Where is the mistake here?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I found a situation that asks me to find mistakes in various coding positions. Here we have two classes

Class A which functions as a super class

```
package TestSes;

public class A {
    private int a = 100;

    public void setA( int value) {
        a = value;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

And this is it's subclass

```
package TestSes;

public class TestA extends A {
    private int a = 222;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main(): ");
        System.out.println("a = "+a );
        a = 123;
    }
}
```

I want to know the mistake here. Please I want a full explanation especially concerning the variable 
a. How can I correct this code to make it work?

Comment: You could just throw this in an IDE, you know..

Comment: What value do you think should be printed (100, 222 or 123)?

Comment: I think private fields cannot be instantiated.  So the TestA class has its own field a (not inherited from A). So I think the printed value will be 222.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel  I am not seeking to throw this an IDE. I am trying to learn how it works. I tried throwing it but I could understand nothing. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You are almost right. A has a private field a. Because it is private it is not possible to access this value from TestA without calling getA(). So if main were an *instance* method of TestA, it would print 222. But  a method that is not an instance method is a static method. Because main is static is has nothing to do with a particular instance of TestA, so it wouldn't make sense to read 222 from main.

Comment: So look at the error messages it tells you and google what they do. This is so often answered already.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel it would be easier to answer this and let laziness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to access and assign a value to a non static variable `a` in your static main method. That's not possible. `a` must be associated with an instance of class `TestA`, so it can't be accessed without an instace.

Comment: Would this also be a scope issue? Can you access 'a' in any method without saying 'this.a'

Comment: @JoshEngelsma In a non static method, you can access `a` without the `this` keyword.

Comment: Mr @Eran. Thanks for your explanation .What is the reason we cant access the non static fields from  a static method? And why it is necessary to use the this operator? Can you explain things deeper ?

Comment: @pentanol Each instance of `TestA` has its own `a` variable. When you try to access `a` from a static method, the compiler doesn't know which instance of `TestA` to take `a` from (there may not be any instance of `TestA` to take `a` from, if you never created an instance of `TestA`). `this` can be used in any non static method. In such methods, this.a and a are equivalent. Using `this.a` If you have a non static method that accepts an argument named `a`, you must refer to the instance variable `a` with `this.a` in order to distinguish between the two `a`s.

Answer (score 0):

You have two concerns there in your code.

1. Your variable `a` is a instance variable, means, it belongs to an object on class `TestA`. You can't access it without an instance ot `TestA`. But, in your static main method, your are accessing it without an instance of `TestA`
2. Your super Class `TestSes` has a instance variable `a`, but, it won't be inherited to your subclass, since, your super class variable is private.

Comment: It is not necessary to access it from an instance. If so what is the role of getters and setters ?

Comment: @pentanol, I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean it is not necessary to access an instance variable from an object to change it.

Comment: instance variable should be associated to an instance, otherwise, you can't access them